# Error Bad argument type : fixnump : nil when calling second function

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I'm trying to create an array of lists with its elements being: `Surname` , `Name` and `Age`.

Here is my code in AutoLISP:

```
(defun C:DP_ADINREG ( / prenume nume varsta inreg)
 (initget 1)
 (setq prenume (getstring "\nIntroduceti prenumele: "))
 (initget 1)
 (setq nume (getstring "\nIntroduceti numele: "))
 (initget 7)
 (setq varsta (getint "\nIntroduceti varsta: "))
 (setq inreg (list (cons 'pn prenume) (cons 'nf nume)
 (cons 'v varsta))
 DP_DATA (append DP_DATA (list inreg))
 )
 (princ)
 )

(defun C:DP_LISTARE ( / curent inreg n)
 (setq curent DP_DATA
       n 1)
 (while curent
 (setq inreg (car curent)) 
 (princ (strcat "\nInregistrarea #" (itoa n)
 ": " (cdr (assoc 'pn inreg))
 ", " (cdr (assoc 'nf inreg))
 ". Varsta " (itoa (cdr (assoc 'v inreg)))
 )
 )
 (setq curent (cdr curent) 
 n (1+ n)
 )
 )
 (princ)
 )
```

Problem is, when trying to access the second function, it gives me an error called:

> Bad argument type : fixnump : nil.

Now I have no idea where the problem actually is.

Any ideas?

Comment: if assoc returns nil (when 'v is missing from the list) the cdr is nil too, and itoa will fail (guessing from how other Lisp dialects work)

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> ; error: bad argument type: fixnump: nil

Arises when a function requiring an integer argument is supplied with a value of `nil`. Hence, this error is arising from the evaluation of the second of your two `itoa` expressions:

```
(itoa (cdr (assoc 'v inreg)))
```

(Since the first `itoa` expression is being supplied with the variable `n`, which cannot be `nil`).

This implies that the following expression returns `nil`:

```
(cdr (assoc 'v inreg))
```

Which implies that one of the association lists within the list held by your global variable `DP_DATA` does not contain a dotted pair with key `v`. I would therefore suggest checking the value held by your global variable `DP_DATA`.

---

Aside: note that `initget` has no effect on a `getstring` prompt - you can achieve the same effect using a basic `while` loop, e.g.:

```
(while (= "" (setq prenume (getstring "\nIntroduceti prenumele: ")))
    (princ "\nPlease enter a first name.")
)
(while (= "" (setq nume (getstring "\nIntroduceti numele: ")))
    (princ "\nPlease enter a surname.")
)
```

---

You can account for null values in your association list using some basic error checking:

```
(defun C:DP_ADINREG ( / prenume nume varsta )
    (while (= "" (setq prenume (getstring "\nIntroduceti prenumele: ")))
        (princ "\nPlease enter a first name.")
    )
    (while (= "" (setq nume (getstring "\nIntroduceti numele: ")))
        (princ "\nPlease enter a surname.")
    )
    (initget 7)
    (setq varsta  (getint "\nIntroduceti varsta: ")
          DP_DATA (cons (list (cons 'pn prenume) (cons 'nf nume) (cons 'v varsta)) DP_DATA)
    )
    (princ)
)

(defun C:DP_LISTARE ( / n )
    (setq n 0)
    (foreach lst (reverse DP_DATA)
        (princ
            (strcat
                "\nInregistrarea #" (itoa (setq n (1+ n)))
                ": " (cond ((cdr (assoc 'pn lst))) (""))
                ", " (cond ((cdr (assoc 'nf lst))) (""))
                ". Varsta " (itoa (cond ((cdr (assoc 'v lst))) (0)))
            )
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

The above will return a blank first name/surname where not present, and an age of `0` where not present; you could alternatively return an error if these values are not present, e.g.:

```
(defun C:DP_LISTARE ( / n nf pn v )
    (setq n 1)
    (foreach lst (reverse DP_DATA)
        (if
            (and
                (setq pn (cdr (assoc 'pn lst)))
                (setq nf (cdr (assoc 'nf lst)))
                (setq v  (cdr (assoc 'v lst)))
            )
            (princ (strcat "\nInregistrarea #" (itoa n) ": " pn ", " nf ". Varsta " (itoa v)))
            (princ (strcat "\nMissing data for item " (itoa n)))
        )
        (setq n (1+ n))
    )
    (princ)
)
```